# BMO2 2016/17 Geometry

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Consider a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$. The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $P$, and the rays $AD$ and $BC$ meet at $Q$. The internal angle bisector of $\angle BQA$ meets $AC$ at $R$ and the internal angle bisector of $\angle APD$ meets $AD$ at $S$. Prove that $RS$ is parallel to $CD$.

Answer (score 3):

$$SR \parallel CD \Leftrightarrow \frac {AS}{SD} = \frac{AR}{RC}$$
Since $PS$ is the internal bisector of $\widehat{APD}$, we have $\large\frac {AS}{SD} = \frac {AP}{PD}$. Similarly, $\large\frac {AR}{RC} = \frac {AQ}{QC}$.
$$\triangle{QAB} \sim \triangle{QCD} \Rightarrow \frac{AQ}{QC} = \frac{AB}{CD}$$
$$\triangle{PAB} \sim \triangle{PCD} \Rightarrow \frac{AP}{PD} = \frac{AB}{CD}$$
Hence, $SR \parallel CD$.

[image]